# My jQuery fade in effect doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

This fade in / fade out effect with jQuery  isn't working.
I dont get an error. The Menu is rendered perfectly and working
However there is no delay or fade with menu on hover.
Here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wAhTc/).
I am using jQuery 1.9.1. I dont want to post the CSS as it is too huge and would take up place. Also the issue i presume is with the jQuery and not the CSS.

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Javascript </a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3.1 jQuery</a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">3.2 Mootools</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">3.3 Prototype</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(" #nav li").hover(

    function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').stop(true, true).delay(1000).fadeIn("slow")
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('ul:first').stop(true, true).delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
    }

    )

});
```

CSS

Comment: You can just do this with a CSS3 transition.

Comment: There is a delay without your css: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/P9cvk/

Comment: The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. better use `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This CSS part is messing with your JS:

```
#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Remove it (or just modify it) and you will get back your delay.

Answer (score 0):

only this part is messing all the things.

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/wAhTc/6/

```
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using CSS hover as well as jQuery hover effect for your menu. You are supposed to be using only one of them. Following code should be removed from your CSS to get things working.

```
#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

Another thing I would suggest is to remove `.delay(100)` from your JS code. You are already using `.fade('slow')` which serves the purpose.